# Fail to pull docker image using Docker for Windows via SSL

Tags: docker, ssl, windows-10

I use docker engine 2.0.0.0-win77 (28777). On my macOS I have succeeded in pulling images from my company's private docker registry. Then I want to do this on my Windows machine. Before I do anything, I have:

```
> docker pull <company.docker.url>/<some image>
Error response from daemon: Get https://<company.docker.url>/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Then, I imported the certificates into my Windows user certificates store.
Now I have:

```
> docker pull <company.docker.url>/<some image>
Error response from daemon: Get https://<company.docker.url>/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure
```

After this failure I have tried:

- Imported the certificates into my Windows global certificates store.
- Copied the files `client.cert`, `client.key` and `ca.crt` to my Windows 10 into:

  - `C:\ProgramData\Docker\certs.d\<company.docker.url>\`
  - `C:\Users\<user>\.docker\certs.d\<company.docker.url>\`

Sadly, I still get this:

```
> docker pull <company.docker.url>/<some image>
Error response from daemon: Get https://<company.docker.url>/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure
```

Two more things to notice:

- If I switch to Windows Containers, I can successfully login or pull images, only fails with Linux Containers version.
- My private cert is signed by an intermediate cert, and the intermediate cert is contained in my `client.cert`.

Some references I have read:

- [Verify repository client with certificates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/)
- [Unable to connect to registry with client certificate signed by intermediate certificate](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21148)
- [Docker Registry SSL CA cert location on windows?](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21189)
- [Docker for Windows FAQ of certificates](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#certificates)

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the tls dir to docker client? `docker --tls-cert=C:\ProgramData\Docker\certs.d\docker.company.net\client.cert --tls-key=C:\ProgramData\Docker\certs.d\docker.company.net\client.key --tls-cacert=C:\ProgramData\Docker\certs.d\docker.company.net\ca.crt pull <company.docker.url>/<some image>`. Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/

Comment: @Robert, I don't think this is the issue because I think `--tls*` options are used for connecting to docker daemon, which is running in localhost. My problem is fail to connect the remote docker registry.

Comment: @Robert I also tried the command you suggested and get: `error during connect: Post https://127.0.0.1:2376/v1.37/images/create?fromImage=docker.compayn.net%2Ftradeshift-proxy&tag=148fbf3b3db5849f73675147c0f14def8766ee21: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2376: connectex: No connection could be
made because the target machine actively refused it.` You can see it tries to connect 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I see, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I would try two things:

- Did you tried: **docker login** first before to pull the images?
- Restart the client and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on windows, too. In my case, restarting the docker daemon helped.

Comment: Did you use the Windows containers? I found that I would only fail while using Linux Containers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem to establish TLS connection to `company.docker.url`. Possible problems:

- `company.docker.url` allows only ciphers, which are not supported by your Linux Containers. Test `company.docker.url` with https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh and compare detected cipher list with supported cipher list of Linux Containers. (I guess Linux Containers = some Hyper-V VM, where you can debug TLS connectivity directly).
- order of leaf and intermediate cert must be in the specific order in your cert file  to form proper certificate chain - from Golang doc https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#LoadX509KeyPair:

  > The certificate file may contain intermediate certificates following the leaf certificate to form a certificate chain.

Answer (score 0):

When I was messing with docker last week the program said you need windows 10 professional and I only had home version so I couldn't get it working, check your version of windows 10 as a suggestion.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment, please try to elaborate to really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, our Sophos firewall blocked the access. I connected directly to the internet and it worked. I have to ask my colleagues, why it is blocked.